# Definition of a "walk" in a graph and associated theorem

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Page 2, chapter 1 of *Algebraic Combinatorics: Walks, Trees, Tableaux, and More*, second edition, by Richard P. Stanley, says the following:

> A *walk* in $G$ of length $\mathcal{l}$ from vertex $u$ to vertex $v$ is a sequence $v_1, e_1, v_2, e_2, \dots, v_{\mathcal{l}}, e_{\mathcal{l}}, v_{\mathcal{l} + 1}$ such that:
>
> - Each $v_i$ is a vertex of $G$.
> - Each $e_j$ is an edge of $G$.
> - The vertices of $e_i$ are $v_i$ and $v_{i + 1}$, for $1 \le i \le \mathcal{l}$.
> - $v_1 = u$ and $v_{\mathcal{l} + 1} = v$.
>
> **1.1 Theorem.** *For any integer $\mathcal{l \ge 1}$, the $(i, j)$-entry of the matrix $\mathbf{A}(G)^\mathcal{l}$ is equal to the number of walks from $v_i$ to $v_j$ in $G$ of length $\mathcal{l}$.*
>
> *Proof.* This is an immediate consequence of the definition of matrix multiplication. Let $\mathbf{A} = (a_{ij})$. The $(i, j)$-entry of $\mathbf{A}(G)^\mathcal{l}$ is given by
> $$(\mathbf{A}(G)^\mathcal{l})_{ij} = \sum a_{i{i_1}} a_{{i_1} {i_2}} \cdots a_{i_{\mathcal{l} - 1} j},$$
> where the sum ranges over all sequences $(i_1, \dots, i_{\mathcal{l} - 1})$ with $1 \le i_k \le p$. But since $a_{rs}$ is the number of edges between $v_r$ and $v_s$, it follows that the summand $a_{i{i_1}} a_{{i_1} {i_2}} \cdots a_{i_{\mathcal{l} - 1} j}$ in the above sum is just the number (which may be $0$) of walks of length $\mathcal{l}$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$ of the form
> $$v_i, e_j, v_{i_1}, e_2, \dots, v_{i_{\mathcal{l} - 1}}, e_\mathcal{l}, v_j$$
> (since there are $a_{ii_1}$ choices for $e_1$, $a_{i_1 i_2}$ choices for $e_2$, etc.) Hence summing over all $(i_1, \dots, i_{\mathcal{l} - 1})$ just gives the total number of walks of length $\mathcal{l}$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$, as desired.

It's not clear to me that this proof makes sense / is valid. Firstly, the author simply declares that "the $(i, j)$-entry of $\mathbf{A}(G)^\mathcal{l}$ is given by $(\mathbf{A}(G)^\mathcal{l})_{ij} = \sum a_{i{i_1}} a_{{i_1} {i_2}} \cdots a_{i_{\mathcal{l} - 1} j},$ where the sum ranges over all sequences $(i_1, \dots, i_{\mathcal{l} - 1})$ with $1 \le i_k \le p$", but fails to *show* this, which would be necessary in order to have a valid proof, no? Secondly, what's going on with the indices of $a_{i{i_1}} a_{{i_1} {i_2}} \cdots a_{i_{\mathcal{l} - 1} j}$? I thought that it might be a typo, until I saw it repeated later. Please help me make sense of this.

---

### EDIT

With regards to the subscripts, why do the $i$ and $j$ of $a_{ij}$ have further subscripts? And then, why do some of the subscripts of the $i$ and $j$ in $a_{i{i_1}}$ and $a_{i_{\mathcal{l} - 1} j}$ not have subscripts?

### EDIT2

After thinking about this for a while, I think one of my main problems with understanding $(\mathbf{A}(G)^\mathcal{l})_{ij} = \sum a_{i{i_1}} a_{{i_1} {i_2}} \cdots a_{i_{\mathcal{l} - 1} j}$ is that I'm not understanding how the matrix multiplication works with the powers, and then how *that* works with the context of "walks".

Answer (score 1):

We could avoid using nested indices and needing to understand the $k^{\text{th}}$ power of a matrix all at once, if we prove the theorem by induction.

Let $W_l$ be the $n \times n$ matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry counts the number of walks from $v_i$ to $v_j$ in $G$ of length $l$. We want to show that actually, this notation is needed only very temporarily: $W_l$ is actually just $A^l$, where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of $G$.

Let's prove this by induction on $l$. Our base case is $l=1$. Here, $W_1$ is the $n \times n$ matrix counting walks of length $1$ between vertices of $G$. A walk of length $1$ between vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$ is just an edge whose endpoints are $v_i$ and $v_j$, and entry $a_{ij}$ of matrix $A$ is precisely the number of such edges. Therefore $W_1 = A = A^1$.

Now, for some $l \ge 1$, assume that $W_{l-1} = A^{l-1}$, and let's look at an arbitrary $(i,j)$ entry of the next case, $W_l$. We can describe the walks from $v_i$ to $v_j$ of length $l$ recursively as follows:

1. First, we take $l-1$ steps to go from $v_i$ to some vertex $v_k$, which could be any of the $n$ vertices of $G$.
2. Then, we take one more step to go from $v_k$ to $v_j$.

For each choice of $k$, the number of ways to do step 1 is the $(i,k)$ entry of $W_{l-1}$, which by our inductive hypothesis is $(A^{l-1})_{ik}$. Then, the number of ways to do step 2 is the number of edges with endpoints $v_k$ and $v_j$, which is $a_{kj}$. Therefore, for each choice of $k$, there are $(A^{l-1})_{ik} a_{kj}$ walks from $v_i$ to $v_j$ whose next-to-last stop is $v_k$, and the total number of walks from $v_i$ to $v_j$ is $$\sum_{k=1}^n (A^{l-1})_{ik} a_{kj}.$$
Now, we realize that this is very similar to the formula for the product of two matrices $P$ and $Q$: $$(PQ)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n p_{ik} q_{kj}.$$ Here, the matrix playing the role of $P$ is $A^{l-1}$, and the matrix playing the role of $Q$ is $A$. We conclude that the number of length-$l$ walks from $v_i$ to $v_j$ is equal to the $(i,j)$ entry of $A^{l-1} A$, or just $A^l$.

Since $i$ and $j$ were arbitrary, this is true for all $i$ and $j$, so we conclude that $W_l = A^l$. By induction, this is true for all $l \ge 1$.

(It is even true for $l=0$, if we take $A^0 = I$, and say that a walk of length $0$ is a walk that starts at a vertex, does nothing, and ends at that same vertex.)

Answer (score 0):

Formula for computing the $(i,j)$-entry of the $l$th degree of the matrix $A$:
$$
(A^l)_{ij}=\sum_{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_{l-1}} a_{i,i_1}a_{i_1,i_2}\ldots a_{i_{l-1},j}
$$
immediately follows from the rule of matrix multiplication. Here $a_{i,j}$ means the element of matrix $A$ at the intersection of the $i$-th row and $j$-th column. Try, for example, to compute the $(i,j)$-entry for matrix $A^3=A\cdot A\cdot A$.
Further, in the specified sum non-zero (and therefore equal to 1) are those and only those summands that correspond to some path from $i$ to $j$. Actually, this path is specified in the text quoted by you.

Comment: What exactly is $A^3$ (or $\mathbf{A}(G)^\mathcal{l}$)? And I can't really tell what this has to do with matrix multiplication, since, as I said, it isn't clear what the indices $a_{i{i_1}} a_{{i_1} {i_2}} \cdots a_{i_{\mathcal{l} - 1} j}$ are supposed to mean (what is $a_{i{i_1}}$ and $a_{i_{\mathcal{l} - 1} j}$ supposed to mean?). This answer doesn't really answer anything – it just leads to the same questions that I had in my post.

Comment: Added a few things. Have you ever had to multiply matrices?

Comment: Of course. But look at the indices for $a_{i{i_1}}$ and $a_{i_{\mathcal{l} - 1} j}$! I have studied plenty of linear algebra, but I have never seen index notation written like this. It simply isn't clear to me what is going on here – it looks like a typo rather than legitimate use of index notation.

Comment: Could you please clarify what confuses you about the $a_{i,i_1}$ or $a_{ii_1}$ entry. I am used to putting a comma between complex indices.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the fact that it's "complex indices" is what I don't understand. For an $m \times n$ matrix $A$, I'm used to seeing elements of row $i$ and column $j$ specified as $a_{ij}$. So maybe I'm misunderstanding what the author is trying to say.

Comment: Why do the $i$ and $j$ of $a_{ij}$ have further subscripts? And then, why do some of the subscripts of the $i$ and $j$ in $a_{i{i_1}}$ and $a_{i_{\mathcal{l} - 1} j}$ not have subscripts?

Comment: Perhaps this expression would look more aesthetically pleasing: $$a_{i,k_1}a_{k_1,k_2}\ldots a_{k_{l-1},j}.$$ Here $i$ and $j$ are the row and column number of matrix $A^l$ respectively, and $k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_{l-1}$ are the summation indices. In this case you probably wouldn't have this question.

Answer (score 0):

The aditional subscrips are for indicating walks, so $a_{i_k i_{k+1}}$ means the $k$-edge in the walk, that joins $v_{i_k}$ with $v_{i_{k+1}}$, so the proof uses that if you choose a path with vertex of indices $i,i_1, \dots i_{n-1}, j$ there are $a_{ii_1} \cdot a_{i_1i_2}\dots a_{i_{n-1}j}$ many walks of with those vertex in that order.

And you can see it better in $A\cdot A$ that
$$(A^2)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n  a_{ik}a_{kj}$$

That each multiplication is:

(how many vextex are between $v_i$ and $v_k)\cdot($how many vextex are between $v_k$ and $v_j$) = the amount of paths with vertex $v_i,v_k,v_j$. and the sum over $k$ will the amount walk of length 2 between $v_i$ and $v_j$. And with that in mind you can prove it for $A^n$.